# How to change window styles in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, dialog

I'm pretty new to WPF and I need to customize a window to look like this:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/2dtb0hh.jpg]

The default model is this:

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/r76lno.jpg]

I want to know what to use and if there are any tutorials on the internet that can help me achieve this. I searched the internet but I couldn't find anything similar to what I want to achieve.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your exact problem? Also, you can't simply change standard message boxes' appearance. You'll have to create your own one.

Answer (score 1):

The below example creates a requested WPF window.

**NOTES:**

1. Setting the [WindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute to "None" hides the standard OS chrome
2. The image referenced in the below example is not included
3. The [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will need to be handled for the "Yes" and "No" buttons

```xml
<Window x:Class="CustomConfirmBox.ConfirmBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ConfirmBox" Height="275" Width="376"
        WindowStyle="None" >
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="38" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="CornflowerBlue" >
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Image x:Name="ConfirmIcon" Margin="6" Source="Icon.jpg" />
        <TextBlock Text="Confirmation" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="63"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="30" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20" >
        Meter data and logs are deleted from the application immediately once
        archiving is complete, while structures are kept in the application.
      </TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="6" >
        Are you sure you want to continue?
      </TextBlock>
      <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ButtonYes" Content="Yes"
                Background="White" Height="25" Width="73" BorderBrush="LightGray" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" x:Name="ButtonNo" Content="No"
                Background="White" Height="25" Width="73" BorderBrush="LightGray" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I did it and looks just like it. I just need to make the window draggable by the first row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about WPF is, that you can style almost everything with custom styles. If you use blend, you can start of really easily, by right clicking on a control and select Styles -> Create Template -> Create copy. The topic itself is quite large, so I'll give you some tutorials to get you started:

- [Control Customization on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278068%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Creating a Control Template (video)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/cc263912.aspx)
- [Google result for "WPF create window template](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/)